# can I access hibernate persisted objects through property members (instead of accessors )?

Tags: hibernate, aop

I understand that the idiom is to define your member variables as private and auto-create getters and setters, and use that in hibernate code.

but I am just curious whether it would work if I don't define getters/setters, and directly refer to the member variables/properties (now made public).

in the following code App.java, the line

"
            System.out.println("loaded " + emp2.account.getAccountNumber());
"

here emp2 is a persisted obj (loaded from db), I can actually refer to the "account" member directly, but somehow when I refer to account.accountNumber directly, it gives me a null, so I had to use account.getAccountNumber();

so why are these 2 cases giving different results?

--- somehow I seemed to have gotten the "direct member access" to work across all cases. but now I can't find how.

Thanks
Yang

File: App.java

```
    package yy.learnhibernate;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SessionFactory factory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

        AccountEntity acct;
        EmployeeEntity emp;
        acct = new AccountEntity();
        acct.accountNumber= "fakeNumber";
        emp = new EmployeeEntity();
        emp.firstName = "f";
        emp.account = acct;

        Session session1 = factory.openSession();
        session1.beginTransaction();
        session1.save(acct);
        session1.save(emp);

        emp = new EmployeeEntity();
        emp.firstName = "f2";
        emp.account = acct;
        session1.save(emp);
        //
        session1.getTransaction().commit();
        session1.close();

        session1 = factory.openSession();
        session1.beginTransaction();

        AccountEntity acct2 = (AccountEntity) session1.load(AccountEntity.class, 1);
        EmployeeEntity emp2 = (EmployeeEntity) session1.get(EmployeeEntity.class, 1);
        System.out.println("loaded " + emp2.account.getAccountNumber());

        for (EmployeeEntity e : acct2.getEmployee()) {
            System.out.println("seen employee" + e.firstName);
        }

        acct2.setAccountNumber("changed ");
        // session1.update(acct2);
        session1.getTransaction().commit();

    }
}
```

File: AccountEntity.java

```
package yy.learnhibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Account")
public class AccountEntity implements Serializable {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1770939417652939285L;
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer accountId;

    @Column
    public String accountNumber;


    public String getAccountNumber() {
        return accountNumber;
    }

    public void setAccountNumber(String accountNumber) {
        this.accountNumber = accountNumber;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "account")
//  @Transient
    // We will define the association here
    public Set<EmployeeEntity> employee = new HashSet<EmployeeEntity>();



    public Integer getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(Integer accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }



    public Set<EmployeeEntity> getEmployee() {
        return employee;
    }

    public void setEmployee(Set<EmployeeEntity> employee) {
        this.employee = employee;
    }
//
//  // Getters and Setters are not shown for brevity
}
```

EmployeeEntity.java

```
package yy.learnhibernate;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "Employee")
public class EmployeeEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1798070786993154676L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Integer employeeId;
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", unique = false, nullable = false, length = 100)
    public String firstName;


    @ManyToOne
    // We will define the association here
    public AccountEntity account;


    public Integer getEmployeeId() {
        return employeeId;
    }

    public void setEmployeeId(Integer employeeId) {
        this.employeeId = employeeId;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }



    public AccountEntity getAccount() {
        return account;
    }

    public void setAccount(AccountEntity account) {
        this.account = account;
    }

    // Getters and Setters are not shown for brevity
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the persistence provider (Hibernate, TopLink, etc.), does not use the class directly, they create a [proxy](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-proxies.html), so when you try to acces the methods, they internally use this proxy to load the right data, this mean that they do not just use the class accessing the member, they can resolve lazy loading or other kind of stuff.
Same goes for Java EE injection part, they always use proxys to emulate the same class but adding some specific behaviour, so reflection use the methods and not the variables for the proxy

Comment: thanks. I understand the proxy/AOP part. but I just wonder why I was able to access the emp2.account directly. supposedly it should give me a null, but in this case it did pull the actual object (note it's not just the account_id stored in the table ).

Answer (score 0):

actually, I found the answer, the reason is due to the difference in load() and get().  the latter gives a real object impl, while the first one gives a proxy. when u use get(), even direct property member accesses are also caught by AOP and necessary extra operations (save to db, expand to associations etc) are added